How to bypass policies when merging using Create PR task for a specific account
I am trying to use the Create PR task in a pipeline to merge changes from my source branch to target branch (master). I want to bypass the policies of having reviewers and linking work item. I changed the configuration for my project collection service account(which creates the automated PR) for contribute to pull request to "Allow", Bypass policies while completing pull requests to "Allow", Bypass policies when pushing to "Allow". However, the policy is not getting bypassed and I still get the prompt to link work items to complete my PR.
So I am using the create PR task which automatically creates a PR in a classic pipeline. According to my project, it is the Project collection build service account that generates this PR. So I enabled the below permissions for it. Now, it creates a PR successfully but while merging to master it still goes through the policies which exist for master branch even though i have set the bypass policies to true.
permission
Now, the solution mentioned above for build validation only has option to check for build success status. I specifically want to bypass the reviewer, work item linking policy just for this one account. I migrated to repositories -> branch -> master and there I provided the above account with permissions.
basically, i do not want to bypass for all user accounts, i want to bypass for 'project collection build service' which i already did. But if you check the below screenshot, i still see the rejection to merge because of not linking work item and not providing reviwers.
PR
Does this have to do something with respect to:
Configured policies are always evaluated for pull request changes. For users that have bypass policy permissions, the reported policy status is advisory only. If the user with bypass permissions approves, the failure status doesn't block pull request completion. reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser
Because i am logged in with my user name and not as project collection build service account.
Master branch policies : policies
Screenshot of my scope scope

Update
Based on the update, here are the permissions set as Allow for the pipeline service account, which should be sufficient to run the sample pipeline below to create a new PR and proceed to complete the PR with branch policies bypassed.

Since my job authorization scope to Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines is toggled off, I have granted the permissions for the pipeline service account Project Collection Build Service (DefaultCollection).
pool: Default

variables:
  Reviewer1: AZ\Alvin

steps:
- task: CreatePullRequest@1
  displayName: 'create pull request to update assembly version'
  inputs:
    repoType: 'Azure DevOps'
    repositorySelector: 'currentBuild'
    sourceBranch: 'release_pipeline/UpdateVersions'
    targetBranch: 'master'
    title: 'Updating Assembly Version'
    description: 'Updating Assembly Version to $(Version)'
    reviewers: 'req:$(Reviewer1)'
    linkWorkItems: false
    bypassPolicy: true
    bypassReason: 'Bypass branch policy to merge'


To Allow Bypass policies when pushing is not necessary since the change is updated to the target branch by git merge of a PR rather than by a force git push.

If a user doesn't has the permission to Bypass policies when completing pull requests, the user will be prevented to Complete the PR by those policies protecting the target branch.

If the permission to Bypass policies when completing pull requests is set as Allow for a user or a group of users, they can still see the branch policies are still not passed; while trying to Complete the PR, they can also see the option to override those policies with an input reason.

You haven't shared how you intend to complete the PR with the pipeline service account. Let's assume you run the az repos pr update command in the sample pipeline below to bypass the branch policies and complete PR.
variables:
  prId: 99

steps:
- pwsh:
    az repos pr update `
     --id $(prId) `
     --bypass-policy true `
     --bypass-policy-reason "Force merge" `
     --status completed
  displayName: Bypass branch policies and complete PR
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken) # Authenticate against the $(System.AccessToken) of the pipeline service account which is granted with the permission to Bypass policies when completing pull requests

It also works the same way as a user does.


Please pay attention to assign this permission for the corresponding or both pipeline service account(s) to the Job authorization scope in your Organization & Project Settings. In the sample above, my setting to Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines was toggled OFF, therefore, I ran the YAML pipeline, which authenticated against the token of Project Collection Build Service (MyOrgName) whom was granted with the required permission.

I have edited the original question to include the screenshot of my scope. It is toggled Off

Do i have to add permission to force push?

I intend to create a PR and bypass it as follows:
task: CreatePullRequest@1
displayName: 'create pull request to update assembly version'
inputs:
bypassPolicy: true
bypassReason: 'Bypass branch policy to merge'
sourceBranch: 'release_pipeline/UpdateVersions'
targetBranch: 'master'
title: 'Updating Assembly Version'
description: 'Updating Assembly Version to $(Version)'
reviewers: 'req:$(Reviewer1)'

We do not use a public cloud based devops but an on premises solution. And my repository is not github it is ADO repository itself. Do I have to add any other code to the above PR task code?

Hi @DharmiMehta, I have updated the answer based on the additional information that shared. Hope it works for you as well. Thx for your time and efforts. Have nice weekends.

Thank you so much! It has finally worked for me.

Hi @DharmiMehta, Glad to know the issue is resolved from your side and you may consider this to help others with similar concerns. Thanks a lot for the efforts

Hi @DharmiMehta, Happy to know the solution to grant required permissions for the pipeline service account works for you. Good luck with the works to go and wish you productive week ahead.
